# Concatenate an input before Dense layer. [Keras with TF backend]

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, vgg-net

So, I need to concatenate an input to the flattened layer before going in the dense layer.
I'm using Keras with TF as backend.

```
model.add(Flatten())
aux_input = Input(shape=(1, )) 
model.add(Concatenate([model, aux_input])) 
model.add(Dense(512,kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay)))
```

I have a scenario like this: X_train, y_train, aux_train. The shape of y_train and aux_train is same (1, ). An image has a ground-truth and an aux_input.

How do I add this aux_input to the model while doing model.fit?

As suggested in answers, I changed my model with functional api. However, now, I get the following error.

> ValueError: Layer dense_1 was called with an input that isn't a
>   symbolic tensor. Received type: . Full input:
>   []. All
>   inputs to the layer should be tensors.

Here's the code for that part.

```
flatten = Flatten()(drop_5)
aux_rand = Input(shape=self.aux_shape)
concat = Concatenate([flatten, aux_input])

fc1 = Dense(512, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay))(concat)
```

Shape of aux input

```
aux_shape = (1,)
```

And then calling the model as follow

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')

aux_rand = np.random.rand(y_train.shape[0])
model_inst = cifar10vgg()
x_train_input = Input(shape=(32,32,3))
aux_input = Input(shape=(1,))
model = Model(inputs=[x_train_input, aux_input], output=model_inst.build_model())
model.fit(x=[x_train, aux_rand], y=y_train, batch_size=batch_size, steps_per_epoch=x_train.shape[0] // batch_size,
                epochs=maxepoches, validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
                callbacks=[reduce_lr, tensorboard], verbose=2)
```

model_inst.build_model() returns `Activation('softmax')(fc2)` which is the output to be fed into the Model (as far as I understood)

Comment: you feed x_train (numpy array) into Model which is not correct! Inputs and outputs of the Model should be Tensor.

Comment: so should it be Input(shape=(image.shape)) ?

Comment: use model_inst.outputs instead of build_model()

Comment: cifar10vgg() is a class which has a method build_model, that returns the output of the model.

Comment: Updated the Model to use tensors (hopefully, that's the correct way to do it). Still getting an error

Answer (score 2):

As I see from your code, you implement the model with [sequential API](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/) which is not a good option in this case. If you have some auxiliary inputs the best way to implement such a feature is to use [functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/).

Here is a [example from Keras website](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models):

```
from keras.layers import Input, Embedding, LSTM, Dense
from keras.models import Model

main_input = Input(shape=(100,), dtype='int32', name='main_input')

x = Embedding(output_dim=512, input_dim=10000, input_length=100)(main_input)

lstm_out = LSTM(32)(x)

auxiliary_output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='aux_output')(lstm_out)
auxiliary_input = Input(shape=(5,), name='aux_input')
x = keras.layers.concatenate([lstm_out, auxiliary_input])

x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)

main_output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='main_output')(x)

model = Model(inputs=[main_input, auxiliary_input], outputs=[main_output, auxiliary_output])
```

---

Based on description, I think following code can give you some intuition:

```
x1 = Input(shape=(32, 32, 3))
flatten1 = Flatten()(x1)

x2 = Input(shape=(244, 244, 3))
vgg = VGG19(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)(x2)
flatten2 = Flatten()(vgg)

concat = Concatenate()([flatten1, flatten2])
d = Dense(10)(concat)

model = Model(inputs=[x1, x2], outputs=[d])
model.compile('adam', 'categorical_crossentropy')
model.fit(x=[x_train1, x_train2],outputs=y_labels)
```

Comment: I'm using VGGNet for this, with a little customization of Concatenate.

Comment: @nirvair no difference! If you have multiple inputs/outputs sequential API is the pain in the neck!

Comment: Essentially, there's only multiple inputs. I don't need multiple outputs. I'll rewrite the model using functional API.

Comment: @nirvair Yep, but the aux input added at the middle of the model.

Comment: So, I rewrote the network. But, how do I write this Model() according to my scenario? Model(inputs=[X_train, aux_input], outputs=[main_output]). Where do I put y_train?

Comment: @nirvair I edited my code, If you need more explanation, please edit your question and specify the issue in more details.

Comment: Umm, I am confused that where should I add y_train (labels) while initializing the model?

Comment: @nirvair You mean, you dont know how to feed them into model.fit()?